# Row Number function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, row-number

I am trying to fetch the specific number of records from a table using cte and Row number function. Whenever I run the query I am getting an error regarding the position of "FROM" clause in the query.
Please suggest the reason behind this error as I am new to Sql.

Error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 3 Column: 10**

code:

```
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        *, row_number() over (order by a.v_prt_nbr_spr) as rw_number
    FROM
        cf_active_pn_master a
        INNER JOIN cf_conn_support b ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id
    WHERE
        a.v_prt_nbr_spr LIKE 'HQCD%'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
where rw_number between 5000 and 10000;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `*` with anything else added to your `SELECT` list, you have to alias the `*`:

```
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        a.*, row_number() over (order by a.v_prt_nbr_spr) as rw_number
    FROM cf_active_pn_master a . . .
```

If you want both `a` and `b` columns, you have to list at least one of them out fully because `a.*,b.*` would return duplicate `obj_id` columns and that's not permitted in a query block that is a view for another block. So:

```
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        a.*, 
        b.col1,
        b.col2,
        b.col3,
        row_number() over (order by a.v_prt_nbr_spr) as rw_number
    FROM
        cf_active_pn_master a
        INNER JOIN cf_conn_support b ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id 
        . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar query against the emp sample table:

```
with cte2 as 
(
  select *
        ,row_number()
          over(
     order by hiredate desc
          ) as rw_number
    from emp e
)
select * from cte2 where rw_number between 5 and 10;

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 9
```

Notice that the error is the same as yours. If you're selecting everying `*` from more than one table, or you select everything and then another column you need to alias the `*`.

```
with cte2 as 
(
  select e.*
        ,row_number()
          over(
     order by hiredate desc
          ) as rw_number
    from emp e
)
select * from cte2 where rw_number between 5 and 10;
```